# objective-c: is method calling inside a class still with selectors or pure calls?

Tags: objective-c, methods, overhead

I am comparing different programming languages and development platforms. One important difference between objective-c and other languages is that it uses selectors, messages, so calling objc_msgSend every time, crossing the boundary of shared library, so introducing a measurable overhead, plus further overhead (little in the cached case) for the objc_msgSend internal functioning, like explained here:
http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/artikel/Optimization/opti-3.html
I am not an expert so I have to trust this article, found on this forum.
On official Apple guide I find that "dot syntax" is just "syntactic sugar", that is the same method calling mechanism is used.
Question: I would like to know if, instead, pure calls are performed inside a class instance, where it would be a waste to call objc_msgSend. That is when one class instance's method is called from a same class instance's method.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Consider this situation in a hypothetical OOP language:

```
class A {
     say_something(){
         print("A!")
     }
     do_something(){
         say_something()
     }
}
```

and

```
class B : extends A {
     say_something(){
         print("B!")
     }
}
```

Now suppose you have an instance of `B`, and call `do_something` :

```
B b;
b.do_something();
```

Should `b` print `A` or `B`? If the call to `say_something` in the implementation of `do_something` goes through the `vtable` (in C++) or `obj_msgSend` (in Obj-C), it will print `B`, but if the compiler decides a call to a method in the same class should call to the method in the same class, it will print `A`.

Which is desirable depends on the situation. So, in C++, you can have a choice, by marking a member function `virtual` or not.
In Objective-C, every method is virtual.

So, even in C++, the optimization you suggested is not done to virtual methods. I won't say a language without virtual methods a proper OOP language.

Anyway, now you might worry it would degrade the performance of an Obj-C app. Apple knows the danger, so they have lots and lots of optimization. For example, in a recent runtime, `objc_msgSend` lives at a fixed address, so that you don't first need to go through the shared-library boundary.

The Mulle-Kybernetic article was also nice, but note also it's very dated: it's whopping ten years ago, which is in this business a pre-historic times. You can read about recent optimizations put in to the implementation of `objc_msgSend` in [bbum's blog posts](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/) or [Hamster's blog posts](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2011/06/17/objc_explain_objc_msgSend_vtable.html).

If you are writing codes managing UI, using the standard messaging (i.e. `objc_msgSend` behind the scenes) is perfectly adequate. It even works very smoothly on mobile devices! So, don't do a premature optimization by getting the `IMP`, etc., until it turns out to be absolutely necessary after measuring the performance of a code.

If you're writing a calculation-intensive code involving, say, tens of thousands of particles moving, yes I would advice against using the Obj-C messaging framework.  In that case, just simply write a C code (which can always be used in Objective-C ) or C++ code (which can be used in Objective-C++.)

Answer (score 1):

All objective-C method calls use obj_msgSend. This is because the code doesn't know the actual real class that is `self`. ie: it could be a subclass with another implementation, or even a proxy for a method that is implement by a remote machine via xmlrpc for example.

AFAIK the you can optimise things yourself by grabbing the implementation of a selector for a given object if you know you're going to send message X to object Y often.

Comment: do you refer to IMP? what a mess to do this for every call inside a class. however is not the compiler able to understand that a instance is calling itself at compile time? very strange. I mean, I have not to use the selector syntax to call a method of the same instance, have I?

Comment: @P5music : Even in C++, a call to the virtual method of a class from inside the implementation of the class's member function, goes through the virtual function table. In Objective-C, every method call is virtual. So it calls through `objc_msgSend` facility. Don't worry, Apple knows `objc_msgSend` is absolutely critical, so they pay a lot of effort to tune it to the full, using hand written assembly and lots of hacks.

Answer (score 0):

it still uses dynamic dispatch via objc_msgSend and variants.

ideally, something similar to a JIT would be produced for objc types.

unlike objc, a c++ compiler *can* use static dispatch for calls to c++ types which are marked virtual *when it can determine the type*.

at any rate, there are many ways to optimize -- you could begin by implementing in c++, and then use objc where it's really handy... but i'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish.